# generate translation file for Zikula module

Tags: symfony, zikula

I have a Zikula module fresh created with modulestudio. By following the instructions in translation.md I used the following command at the ssh shell of my webspace:

```
php app/console translation:extract template --bundle=RKHelperModule --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --output-format=po --dir=./modules/RK/HelperModule --dir=./app/Resources/RKHelperModule
```

The answer of the system is:

```
Could not open input file: app/console
```

app/console is there (permission 644).

How to figure out what is going wrong?

Thanks for helping!

Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you move into the main directory before executing this command.

Comment: I was in my web hosting root instead of my Zikula Installation root. Thanks for the quick reply!